# Using javascript to redirect Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LlUh.png)I'm using javascript that when the clicks the log off button and clicks it redirects them to another page and additional if the user clicks cancel it remains on the page the user was on. My issue is that it is not redirecting but if I put a alert I can get the `alert message`.

Javascript:

```
function Exit() {
     var bResponse = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?');

     if (bResponse) {
         alert("You are being logged out ");
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
     }
     else
    alert ("You may have other options.") //trying the alert 
}
```

HTML Link

```
 <li><a href=""onclick="return Exit()">Log Off </a></li>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code? It should be in the view itself to work this way?

Comment: in _layoutpartial view

Comment: is the url correct in your view source ?

Comment: in which view source?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm

Comment: actually not getting any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Exit() {
     var bResponse = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?');

     if (bResponse) {
         alert("You are being logged out ");
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
     }
     else
    alert ("You may have other options.") //trying the alert 
}
```

```css
#spanId
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<li><span id="spanId" onclick = "Exit();">Log out</span></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><span onclick="Exit()">Log Off </span></li>
```

Comment: Question, how do I let it be inline with the other list items because i'm trying display and style

Comment: @DeanlyDressikie You mean inline style?? So, you want to include style as inline? Right?

Comment: yeah that is what I want to include

Comment: no I'm sorry not that I meant; as in there three items in the list but because of span, the item in span is higher than the other two items.

Comment: show me here these  your other  items in list. Which html tag are you using for other items?

Comment: href I'm using within <li> I have edited the question with a image

Comment: @DeanlyDressikie here is  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOG0GHQEAS3J  all items in list is same styled

Comment: ok thanks for your help. Do you know anything about windows login authentication?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need that `return` statement.
Simply:

```
 <li><a href="" onclick="Exit()">Log Off </a></li>
```

And in your javascript function:

```
window.location.href = 'Index/Home';
```

Comment: That didn't work either once I click ok it just refreshes the page I'm currently on

Comment: what's the file name of the asp.net page your trying to navigate to?

Comment: the home page i'm trying to navigate to when the user clicks ok

Comment: this is mvc, wouldn't be like that?